# Create a Java program that reads a .txt and identifies triangle side lengths

Tags: java, input, output

I am trying to create a Java program that reads three numbers on a line from a text file and interprets them as the length of three sides of a triangle, printing out:

```
"Equilateral" - if the three lines are equal length

"Isosceles" - if only two of the three lines are equal

"Scalene" - for any other valid length

 ...or "Not a Triangle"
```

My text file looks like this...

```
1  1  1

2  2  1

2  x  3
```

So far I have this and don't know where to go from there any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Triangle {

public static void main (String[] args){

File fileName = new File("input.txt");
Scanner scan = null;

try { 
    Scanner file = new Scanner( new File("input.txt");
}
  while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
  }

catch(FileNotFoundException){
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Triangle {

public static void main (String[] args)
{

    File fileName = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner scan = null;
    String str[];
    int s1=0,s2=0,s3=0;
try 
{ 
    Scanner file = new Scanner( new File("input.txt"));
    String line;
    while((line=file.nextLine())!=null)
    {
        str = line.split(" ");

        if(str.length==3)
        {
            try
            {
                s1 = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
                s2 = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
                s3 = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);

                if(s1+s2>=s3 && s2+s3>=s1 && s1+s3>=s2)
                {
                    if(s1==s2 && s2==s3) System.out.println("Equilateral");
                    else if(s1==s2 || s2==s3 || s3==s1) System.out.println("Isosceles");
                    else System.out.println("Scalene");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}

}

}
```

Comment: If you need some explanation please comment

Comment: Thanks sjboss, this helps a lot. Haven't used Interger.parseInt before, but looking up the parts in there that I haven't seen and its coming together. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] line = (scan.nextLine()).split("\\s+");
    if(line.length != 3) {
        // the next line doesn't have exactly 3 integers, do something
    }
    try {
        int side1 = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
        int side2 = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
        int side3 = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
        // check if it is a triangle, and what kind of triangle is it
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        // there is something else in the line, other than integer value(s)
    }
}
```

Here's how you can accept the input (one of the possible ways).

- Check if there are more lines in the input stream.
- If there are more lines, read the next line.
- Tokenise the next line (extract each tokens).
- You are expecting that each line should have exactly 3 integers.
- So, first check if there are exactly 3 tokens in the next line. If no, handle accordingly.
- If there are exactly 3 tokens, try to convert each of them into integers.
- If any of them can't be converted into integers, handle       accordingly.
- If all the 3 tokens are converted into integers successfully, you've got the 3 sides of your triangle. Now you can check whether it is a triangle or not, and what kind of triangle it is.